# How to fix invalid method declaration; return type required?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that lists prime numbers from 1 to 100,000. I've created the following code but I'm getting an error that says "invalid method declaration; return type required"

```
import java.util.*;
public class primenumbers
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        listPrime(A);
        for(int b = 0; b <= A.length(); b++)
        {
            System.out.println(A[b]);
        }
    }
    public static boolean isPrime(int number)
    {
        for(int f = 2; f <= (number/2) + 1; f++)
        {
            if(number % f == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static listPrime(ArrayList<Integer> A)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
        {
            if(isPrime(i)==false)
            {
                A.add(i);
                return A;
            }
        }
        return A;
       }
    }
```

I'm guessing its something super obvious that I'm just overlooking. Thanks.

Comment: You missed the return type here `public static listPrime(ArrayList<Integer> A)` You most likely meant to put `ArrayList<Integer>` after the word static.

Comment: Look at your method declarations. You forgot the return type on one of them, just like the error message is telling you.

Comment: Side note: no need to explicitly compare to `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few errors

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    listPrime(A);  
    for(int b = 0; b < A.size(); b++)  // use size and < not <=
    {
        System.out.println(A.get(b)); // use get and round brackets
    }
}
public static boolean isPrime(int number)
{
    for(int f = 2; f <= (number/2) + 1; f++)
    {
        if(number % f == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static void listPrime(ArrayList<Integer> A)  // return void
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++)
    {
        if(isPrime(i)==false)
        {
            A.add(i);
            //return;  // keep going
        }
    }
    return;  // not really needed
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have not added/specified return type for `listPrime` function.**

replace method declaration with following `public static ArrayList<Integer> listPrime(ArrayList<Integer> A)`